# JavaScript: how to switch between tabs?

Tags: javascript, tabs, xul, switch-statement

So I created some tab using XUL. How can I write JavaScript code so that if I click on a button in tab 1, tab 2 will be shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the tabs element and [set the selected Index property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tabs#p-selectedIndex) to the index of the tab you want.  e.g. if the tabs element is 'mytabs' and you want to select the 2nd tab...

```
document.getElementById("mytabs").selectedIndex = 1;
```

Comment: BTW, can you show me how I can do so that when a button is clicked, a new tab is created?  The idea is I have a list of items in 1 tab, when I click a button, say "Add item", a new tab will be opened so that I can I fill in info about the new item. Thanks in advance.